# Grafana sample Workshop-panel not working - TypeError: a.ReactPanelPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, grafana

Trying to create a panel plugin with react in Grafana.
As shown in their demos, added the workshop-panel created by them and added it my set up.
When running it, getting the error:
Failed to import plugin module TypeError: a.ReactPanelPlugin is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. This it is probably due to grafana latest not yet fully supporting the react plugins.

What I did to solve it:

Use yarn link as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grafana/ui:

> *"For development purposes we suggest using yarn link that will create symlink to @grafana/ui lib. To do so navigate to packages/grafana-ui
>   and run yarn link. Then, navigate to your project and run yarn link
>   @grafana/ui to use the linked version of the lib. To unlink follow the
>   same procedure, but use yarn unlink instead."*

Then in the react panels module.tsx change  `export const reactPanel = new PanelPlugin(MyPanel);` to `export const plugin = new PanelPlugin(MyPanel);`

It worked for me :-)